# Vue - v-if no item with that name in the list then show an image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
<ul class="ulItems" v-for="item in listingItems" :key="item.channels">
  <li class="liItems">
    {{ item.itemName }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to display an image in cases where the list does not contain an object with that name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      listingItems: [{itemName: 'aaa', channels: 1}, {itemName: '', channels: 2}, {itemName: 'bbb', channels: 3}],
      noNameImg: 'https://picsum.photos/50'
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul class="ulItems" v-for="item in listingItems" :key="item.channels">
    <li class="liItems" v-if="item.itemName">
      {{ item.itemName }}
    </li>
    <li class="liItems" v-else>
      <img :src="noNameImg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```